# Add deep link when creating Firebase message

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm using the firebase [Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Message.Builder) class to create push notifications for a react native app. I want the notification to take users to a specific screen of the app. Right now tapping on the push notification just takes users to the last screen they were on before they back-grounded the app. I'm testing this on my iOS device. How can I embed a specific deep link in the message? Would I use `setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig apnsConfig)` or `setFcmOptions(FcmOptions fcmOptions)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the APNS config since this is for an iOS app:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/ApnsConfig.Builder

You could approach it different ways, but you could either include a URL in the header field, and use it for custom deep link logic, or you can have custom data in the `putCustomData(String key, Object value)` and then have your app process that info to deep link into the correct part of your app.

Your app would process this notification in the `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application

Comment: would the custom data or URL be in the `userInfo` object from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?

Comment: also my app is actually a react native app. If i want the deep link URL to be present in both android and iOS devices, would I use `putData()` in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Message.Builder?

Comment: I have never used that particular data function as the apps I have worked on have been iOS, but I would assume that the data from the putData function should be available in the push on both platforms. Seems like the user below has a react-native specific example.

Answer (score 0):

I had integrated this feature in an app I made in react native aswell. Look at my solution below.

As you can see in the app I am waiting for a notification to come on and I check if it has a type available. My notifications are always routed to another page. In my case its the same page but I set a route as datatype in my payload.

After that you can use that route payload with your naviogator library in my case `react-navigation` to navigate to the correct screen.

You should chose which trigger works best for you ether [onNotificationOpenedApp](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#onNotificationOpenedApp) or [getInitialNotification](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/messaging#getInitialNotification).

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Assume a message-notification contains a "type" property in the data payload of the screen to open
  messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp((remoteMessage) => {
    console.log(
      "Notification caused app to open from background state:",
      remoteMessage
    );
    //navigation.navigate(remoteMessage.data.type);
  });

  // Check whether an initial notification is available
  messaging()
    .getInitialNotification()
    .then((remoteMessage) => {
      if (remoteMessage) {
        console.log(
          "Notification caused app to open from quit state:",
          remoteMessage
        );
        const route = remoteMessage?.data?.route;

        navigation.navigate(route, {
          data: remoteMessage.data,
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("Caught ", error));
}, []);
```